# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess. Sporadically I get this error:

`` System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.get_m_majorVersion()
at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at MyApp.MyScheduler.AddSampleOperation(SampleOperation sampleOperation) ``

It happens specifically when I make a call like:

`_dbContext.SampleOperations.AsNoTracking().First(so => so.SampleOperationId == sampleOperation.SampleOperationId);`

To be clear, this is not a NullReferenceException happening with code that I control. It's happening in the Oracle client code, and it only happens sporadically. I can reproduce the same steps multiple times and the error won't happen, then eventually it does. I tried removing Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client from the GAC, but that didn't help.

I'm hoping someone else has seen this error. I'm using the following versions from NuGet:

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess: 12.1.24160719

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework: 12.1.2400

EntityFramework: 6.1.3

Could it be something that was fixed in a later version Oracle.ManagedDataAccess?

Comment: Version 12.1 was the first release of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess. I would give a try on newer version, i.e. 12.2

Comment: You can now get the Oracle drivers from NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess , so try that.  And also make sure that you're not accessing a DbContext instance from multiple threads, which can cause sporadic failures with any provider.

Comment: I'm going to try upgrading to 12.2. @DavidBrowne-Microsoft question - if all access to the DbContext is always wrapped in a lock, would that prevent the sporadic failures?

Comment: Yes.  The DbContext can be accessed from different threads, just not at the same time.  Although for performance you normally would not do that.

Comment: I'm also getting this error sporadically and having no luck with anything I try.  Have you found any fix for it?

Comment: I upgraded Oracle.ManagedDataAccess via NuGet. I haven't seen the error again, but it was sporadic so I'm not 100% confident that it's fixed yet.

Comment: I actually upgrade to v18.3.0 of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework last week.  No errors until today :(  Same error again.  Does seem like it's situational (IE: hundreds of records process, then all records for 3 or 4 minutes get this error, then more records process afterward).

Comment: @AndyArndt can you let me know if you figure anything else out? I'll let you know too. Thanks!

Comment: I opened a support incident with Oracle to see if they can at least point us in the right direction to finding the issue.  I'll update what I learn.

Comment: I found a place where the db context was being accessed potentially from a separate thread without a lock. That might actually be the underlying cause of this. You might want to search your code for that.

Comment: My resolution is sort of sad.  We were using a CQRS framework in our service.  All of our errors of this type seemed to be coming from calls this framework was making to its event store.  We removed the CQRS framework/pattern and the errors have gone away.  I am certain we could have found the cause, given enough time, but that didn't happen.  I suspect there was some non-thread-safe activities happening inside the library (CQRSLite).

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft How should I access DbContext from multiple threads if a lock isn't a good solution?

Comment: That should probably be a new question, with some more context, not a comment on an old question.